# How to set width and height of popOverController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating a popovercontroller called popoverCamera. I want to set its size as cameraview's size which is default (width-100, hwight-100).
How to set its size to default as cameraview's size?

Here cameraview is a view.

```
popoverCamera= [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                            initWithContentViewController:videoRecorder];
            [popoverCamera presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) inView:self.cameraView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:YOURCONTROLLER];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[senderView bounds] inView:senderView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Change code as per your requirement..

Comment: Here  I am using videoRecorder in popoverController so this code is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing the value of property `popoverContentSize`.Changing the value of this property overrides the default value of the current view controller

Answer (score 0):

From UIPopoverController.h, you can override:

```
/* contentSizeForViewInPopover allows you to set the size of the content from within the view controller. This property is read/write, and you should generally not override it.
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CGSize contentSizeForViewInPopover __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_2);
```

to return the correct value.